# User input in Python without use of enter key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input, enter

How do I do user input in Python where I don't want the user to have to press enter in the console? In this case, it's opening a pdf. I want it to say something like

> "PDF will automatically open. Press  to view in a file browser or q
>   to quit the program"

How can I make it so that the user doesn't have to hit enter, and the input won't show up onscreen? As soon as the user hits <kbd>q</kbd>, I want the program to exit.

As far as I know, both `input()` and `raw_input` require the user to hit enter.

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It varies by operating system.  In answer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user), you can see a recipe to read one character from STDIN on either unix or windows.

I haven't used it, but there is also the [`getch` python pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch) you could try.